# How to use try and except within tkinter? And how to see if a Radio Button is active?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button, try-except

I am making a basic program to calculate the cost of a meal when going out to eat. I am having trouble with two things.

1: When you enter nothing or a non-numerical value into the entry box, instead of nothing happening, I want it to let you know "Hey that didn't work." However nothing happens when I test it.

2: How to see if a Radio Button is active. I made the option to add a tip and if so to add 5%, 10%, 15%, or 20%.

Here is the code for the first problem:

```
    try:
        total_cost = Label(frame_4, text="Your total is %.2f" % total, fg="blue")
        total_cost.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
    except ValueError:
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error",
                                    "One or more of the entries is not numerical. Please go back and fix them.")
```

Here is the code for the second problem:

```
   if tip_1 == ACTIVE:
         tip = dinner * .05
         total = dinner + tax + tip
```

Here is all the code, any indention errors you see are typos (I have surrounded the above errors with asterisks):

```
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter.messagebox

    #Creates the window and frames
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Meal Cost Calculator")
    window.geometry("500x700")
    frame_1 = Frame(window)
    frame_2 = Frame(window)
    frame_3 = Frame(window)
    frame_4 = Frame(window)

    #Sets the Radio Button to 20% automatically
    v = IntVar()
    v.set(4)


    #Creates all the labels and entry boxes
    label_0 = Label(frame_1, text="Enter the cost of each item you have purchased.")
    label_1 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 1")
    label_2 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 2")
    label_3 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 3")
    label_4 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 4")
    label_5 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 5")
    label_6 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 6")
    label_7 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 7")
    label_8 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 8")
    label_9 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 9")
    label_10 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 10")
    label_11 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 11")
    label_12 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 12")
    label_13 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 13")
    label_14 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 14")
    label_15 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 15")
    label_16 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 16")
    label_17 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 17")
    label_18 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 18")
    label_19 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 19")
    label_20 = Label(frame_1, text="Item 20")

    #Allows me to pull the data from the entries and convert them to strings
    svalue_1 = StringVar()
    svalue_2 = StringVar()
    svalue_3 = StringVar()
    svalue_4 = StringVar()
    svalue_5 = StringVar()
    svalue_6 = StringVar()
    svalue_7 = StringVar()
    svalue_8 = StringVar()
    svalue_9 = StringVar()
    svalue_10 = StringVar()
    svalue_11 = StringVar()
    svalue_12 = StringVar()
    svalue_13 = StringVar()
    svalue_14 = StringVar()
    svalue_15 = StringVar()
    svalue_16 = StringVar()
    svalue_17 = StringVar()
    svalue_18 = StringVar()
    svalue_19 = StringVar()
    svalue_20 = StringVar()
    entry_1 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_1)
    entry_2 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_2)
    entry_3 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_3)
    entry_4 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_4)
    entry_5 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_5)
    entry_6 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_6)
    entry_7 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_7)
    entry_8 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_8)
    entry_9 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_9)
    entry_10 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_10)
    entry_11 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_11)
    entry_12 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_12)
    entry_13 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_13)
    entry_14 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_14)
    entry_15 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_15)
    entry_16 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_16)
    entry_17 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_17)
    entry_18 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_18)
    entry_19 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_19)
    entry_20 = Entry(frame_1, textvariable=svalue_20)
    label_21 = Label(frame_3, fg="red", text="*A tip is not mandatory, just courteous.*")
    label_22 = Label(frame_3, text="Please choose a tip amount.")

    #Creates the Radio Buttons and makes them appear as regular buttons
    tip_1 = Radiobutton(frame_3, text="5%", indicatoron=0, width=10, variable=v, value=1)
    tip_2 = Radiobutton(frame_3, text="10%", indicatoron=0, width=10, variable=v, value=2)
    tip_3 = Radiobutton(frame_3, text="15%", indicatoron=0, width=10, variable=v, value=3)
    tip_4 = Radiobutton(frame_3, text="20%", indicatoron=0, width=10, variable=v, value=4)
    tip_5 = Radiobutton(frame_3, text="None", indicatoron=0, width=10, variable=v, value=5)


    #Creates a function to add all the items together and add tax to the total as well as the tip if the user chooses to.
    def cost():
        value_1 = float(svalue_1.get())
        value_2 = float(svalue_2.get())
        value_3 = float(svalue_3.get())
        results = [value_1, value_2, value_3]
        dinner = sum(results)
        tax = dinner * .0825
        if tip_1 == ACTIVE:
             tip = dinner * .05
             total = dinner + tax + tip
       *try:
             total_cost = Label(frame_4, text="Your total is %.2f" % total, fg="blue")
             total_cost.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        except ValueError:                        #Supposed to flag the user that their entry was not valid
             tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error",
                                    "One or more of the entries is not numerical. Please go back and fix them.")
        elif tip_2 == ACTIVE:
             tip = dinner * .10
             total = dinner + tax + tip
        try:
             total_cost = Label(frame_4, text="Your total is %.2f" % total, fg="blue")
             total_cost.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        except ValueError:
             tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error",
                                    "One or more of the entries is not numerical. Please go back and fix them.")
        elif tip_3 == ACTIVE:
             tip = dinner * .15
             total = dinner + tax + tip
        try:
             total_cost = Label(frame_4, text="Your total is %.2f" % total, fg="blue")
             total_cost.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        except ValueError:
             tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error",
                                    "One or more of the entries is not numerical. Please go back and fix them.")
        elif tip_4 == ACTIVE:
             tip = dinner * .20
             total = dinner + tax + tip
        try:
             total_cost = Label(frame_4, text="Your total is %.2f" % total, fg="blue")
             total_cost.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        except ValueError:
             tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error",
                                    "One or more of the entries is not numerical. Please go back and fix them.")
        elif tip_5 == ACTIVE:
             total = dinner + tax
             try:
             total_cost = Label(frame_4, text="Your total is %.2f" % total, fg="blue")
             total_cost.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
        except ValueError:
             tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Error",
                                    "One or more of the entries is not numerical. Please go back and fix them.")*


    #Creates a button to run the cost() function
    button = Button(frame_2, text="Submit", command=cost)

    #Places all the frames, labels, entries, and buttons
    label_0.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
    label_1.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
    label_2.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
    label_3.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
    label_4.grid(row=4, sticky=E)
    label_5.grid(row=5, sticky=E)
    label_6.grid(row=6, sticky=E)
    label_7.grid(row=7, sticky=E)
    label_8.grid(row=8, sticky=E)
    label_9.grid(row=9, sticky=E)
    label_10.grid(row=10, sticky=E)
    label_11.grid(row=11, sticky=E)
    label_12.grid(row=12, sticky=E)
    label_13.grid(row=13, sticky=E)
    label_14.grid(row=14, sticky=E)
    label_15.grid(row=15, sticky=E)
    label_16.grid(row=16, sticky=E)
    label_17.grid(row=17, sticky=E)
    label_18.grid(row=18, sticky=E)
    label_19.grid(row=19, sticky=E)
    label_20.grid(row=20, sticky=E)
    entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    entry_2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    entry_3.grid(row=3, column=1)
    entry_4.grid(row=4, column=1)
    entry_5.grid(row=5, column=1)
    entry_6.grid(row=6, column=1)
    entry_7.grid(row=7, column=1)
    entry_8.grid(row=8, column=1)
    entry_9.grid(row=9, column=1)
    entry_10.grid(row=10, column=1)
    entry_11.grid(row=11, column=1)
    entry_12.grid(row=12, column=1)
    entry_13.grid(row=13, column=1)
    entry_14.grid(row=14, column=1)
    entry_15.grid(row=15, column=1)
    entry_16.grid(row=16, column=1)
    entry_17.grid(row=17, column=1)
    entry_18.grid(row=18, column=1)
    entry_19.grid(row=19, column=1)
    entry_20.grid(row=20, column=1)
    label_21.grid(row=6, columnspan=2)
    label_22.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
    tip_1.grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
    tip_2.grid(row=2, columnspan=2)
    tip_3.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)
    tip_4.grid(row=4, columnspan=2)
    tip_5.grid(row=5, columnspan=2)
    button.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)

    frame_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    frame_2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    frame_3.grid(row=1, column=0)
    frame_4.grid(row=1, column=1)

    #Allows the GUI to remain open
    window.mainloop()
```

Please excuse the repetitiveness of my code, I like to write out as much code as I can (weird I know xD) instead of making it easier.

Please help me, I have been on this for hours and have been searching all over Stack Overflow. The possible answers I did find either didn't work or would involve rewriting my code.

Again please help, and thank you if you do! :D

Comment: please try to cut the code down to the minimum number of lines necessary to illustrate the problem. See [mcve](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

first you would have to extract whats inside the total_cost and do an operation to it. to test if it's an int.

use `type`

I forgot tkinter commands but the gist is

extract the value of total_cost and find it's type

for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,"hello"]
for i in a:
    if str(type(i)) != "<class 'int'>":
        print(i + " is invalid value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rbval = tkinter.IntVar()

radiobutton = tkinter.Radiobutton(<master>, text='RadioButton', variable=rbvar, value =5)

radiobutton2 = tkinter.Radiobutton(<master>, text='RadioButton2', variable=rbvar, value =10)
```

So if you type

```
if rbval.get() == 5:
    <whatever>
```

You can get the value of the selected item..

Is this enough??